# php memory usage much higher on production server

Tags: php, apache, postgresql, laravel

I have a website built with Laravel and Postgresql. The website has debugbar installed for performance measurements. On my local development machine it shows around 4MB memory used, however, on the production server it uses much more - about 40 MB for the same page. That results in about 200 - 300 ms increased loading speed. The websites and their db contents are exactly the same.

My local machine runs Linux Mint 18 with Apache/2.4.18, PHP 7.0, Postgresql 9.5, and using Redis caching.

The production server runs CentOS 6.8 with Apache/2.2.15, PHP 7.0, Postgresql 9.5, and using Redis caching.

Any ideas where should I look for such memory usage difference? Could the OS/Apache version differences provide such increased memory usage?

Comment: .... with same database?

Comment: Do you mean the same db server? No, both servers has their own local db sever, however, the content of the db is the same.

Comment: 4MB memory used for what? what and where you measure?

Answer (score 1):

I find on Apache homepage new feature.

> Reduced memory usage
>
> Despite many new features, 2.4.x tends to use less memory than 2.2.x.

... at here. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/new_features_2_4.html.

I only find an old image to describe that (Apache 2.2).

And you should know CentOS base on Debian use more memory usage than Ubuntu/Linux Mint.

[image]

But I don't think it x10 from 4MB to 40MB.

4MB in your computer too small because when I start Apache/Postgres in my computer least 40MB (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS).

OR

Can be the difference between the profile of two machines. The difference between x86 and x64 version.

Hope this help.